# Drupal 7 deployment: Features with nid references

Tags: deployment, drupal-7

I order to deploy changes from my testing server to a staging server, I have used Features to collect and version a set of views, menu items etc. In one of my views, I refer to a specific nid as intro text for that view. When I deploy to the staging server, another node is showed for that view because that server has another node with that given nid.

My question is: How should I approach this? Can I use an alias insted of nid in the view? Or is there a way to export the node AND keep a fixed nid between the two servers? Or is there a better way?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to use the module [Views UI: Edit Basic Settings](http://drupal.org/project/views_ui_basic).

With this module you can avoid using a node for intro text, instead you can use the Views Header for the intro.